# The property of the sum and product of ordered numbers

Tags: inequality, elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $\mu, \nu, \mu^{\prime}, \nu^{\prime}$ be ordinal numbers, respectively. 
We have the property of summation like below:

$$ \nu < \nu^{\prime} \to \mu + \nu < \mu + \nu^{\prime}$$
$$ \mu < \mu^{\prime} \to \mu + \nu \leqq \mu^{\prime} + \nu$$

Why is the first expression $<$ and the second $\leqq$? 
Where does this difference come from?

I have found several questions similar to this question, but no general proof for these two equations.

1. [Ordinal numbers addition property: $b<c$ implies $b+a \le c+a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911905/ordinal-numbers-addition-property-bc-implies-ba-le-ca)
2. [Ordinal multiplication property: $\alpha<\beta$ implies $\alpha\gamma\le\beta\gamma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912477/ordinal-multiplication-property-alpha-beta-implies-alpha-gamma-le-beta-ga?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The second inequality isn't strict cause we have, e.g. $$0+\omega=1+\omega.$$

To see the first is strict, observe that by definition, $$ \beta + (\alpha + 1) = (\beta + \alpha) + 1 > \beta + \alpha.$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! But $(\beta + \alpha) + 1 > \beta + \alpha$ is rather a result derived from $0 < 1 \to \mu < \mu + 1$?

Comment: It’s part of the inductive definition of ordinal sum.

Comment: What is the "part of the inductive definition"? Cloud you explain it more detail?

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood your question. That’s a good point. The fact that $\alpha+1>\alpha$ needs to be proven separately. (From the definition of ordinal successor, not ordinal addition.)

Comment: (At risk of confusion due to overloading the symbol $\alpha$: in my last comment, I meant the statement that for all ordinals $\gamma$, $\gamma+1>\gamma$.)

Comment: yeah, thanks. let me think of that more.