# Ordinal multiplication property: $\alpha<\beta$ implies $\alpha\gamma\le\beta\gamma$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality, ordinals

I'm having trouble proving the following two ordinal multiplication properties.

1. If $\alpha, \beta$, and $\gamma$ are such that $\alpha \lt \beta$ and $\gamma \gt 0$, then $\alpha\gamma \le \beta\gamma$.
2. If $\alpha, \beta$, and $\gamma$ are such that $\gamma\alpha \lt \gamma\beta$ and $\gamma \gt 0$, then $\alpha \lt \beta$.

Comment: What have you tried already? Note that $\gamma > 0$ just means that $\gamma$ is non-empty. $\alpha < \beta$ means we have an order preserving injection from $\alpha$ to $\beta$, and we have to come up with an order-preserving function from $\alpha\gamma$ into $\beta\gamma$...

Comment: By order preserving, do you mean a strictly increasing function?

Comment: Yes, $x < y$ means $f(x) < f(y)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already proved that inequality of ordinals is trichotomic, then the second part, which has the form of implication
$$\gamma \alpha < \gamma \beta \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \alpha<\beta$$
can be equivalently reformulated as
$$\beta\le\alpha \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad  \gamma\beta\le\gamma\alpha.$$

So now the two parts have very similar form: We have to prove for $\gamma>0$ that

- $\alpha<\beta \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad  \gamma\alpha\le\gamma\beta$
- $\alpha\le\beta \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad  \alpha\gamma\le\beta\gamma$

(I have reversed the notation in the second parts so that the assumption in both parts is similar.)

---

By definition $\alpha\le\beta$ means that the ordinal $\alpha$ is isomorphic to an *initial segment* of the ordinal $\beta$. But it can be shown that this is equivalent to the fact that $\alpha$ is isomorphic to a *subset* of $\beta$. (See for example [Order-isomorphic with a subset iff order-isomorphic with an initial segment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9483/order-isomorphic-with-a-subset-iff-order-isomorphic-with-an-initial-segment). This fact was also mentioned in an answer to [another question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911905/ordinal-numbers-addition-property-bc-implies-ba-le-ca)).

So now we know that $\alpha\le\beta$  and we wonder whether $\gamma\alpha$ can be realized as a subset of $\gamma\beta$; and similarly for $\alpha\gamma$  and $\beta\gamma$.

This is not very difficult: The ordinal $\gamma\alpha$ simply means that we have replaced each point of $\alpha$ by a copy of the ordinal $\gamma$. This can be clearly embedded into "$\beta$-many" copies of $\gamma$.

Similarly, $\alpha\gamma$ means that we have "$\gamma$-many" copies of $\alpha$. If we take "$\gamma$-many" copies of $\beta$, we can embed each copy of $\alpha$ into a copy of $\beta$.

The above is a rather informal argument, I assume you would be able to make it more formal and describe the embeddings between the well-ordered sets we are working with.